# WSO2 ESB 4.7.0 download on server

Tags: download, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

How do we download the 4.7.0 release of the WSO2 ESB directly on the server? I only have a ssh terminal to the server, no GUI.

I tried with wget. With and without auth. Tried the --save-cookies method with wget too without any success.

I tried with elinks & logging in to the wso2 site with my account there, but I got no way of downloading the latest version through a terminal.

Wonder why should a open source project make it so difficult to download a product build?

Can anybody help me a link or a method to download it via a terminal?

Comment: Seems there is already a WSO2 jira bug for this.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2355

Unfortunately there is no comment or reply on the bug either..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try this:

```
wget --user-agent="testuser" --referer="http://connect.wso2.com/wso2/getform/reg/new_product_download" http://dist.wso2.org/products/enterprise-service-bus/4.7.0/wso2esb-4.7.0.zip
```

Comment: Yup. Works as you suggested.